# Excel macro to copy csv files

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to copy data from csv files from a folder into 1 excel sheet...part of my code is below. I would like to know why the data is copied from second row and not first row.

```
With Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
            'MsgBox (MyFile)
            Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rws, 100))
            'MsgBox (Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count())
            Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ActiveWorkbook.Close True
        End With
```

Comment: "From second row" or "to second row"?

Comment: Copy to second row.....but copy all rows so from first row in csv

Comment: `.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` will never be the first row because of the `Offset`.